# $\dim (D-P)=\dim (D)-1$

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, coding-theory, function-fields

I'm trying to prove this question:

> Let $D$ be a divisor in $F|K$ such that $\dim (D)\gt 0$ and $0 \neq
>  f\in \mathscr L(D)$. Thus $f\notin \mathscr L(D-P)$ for almost all $P$.
>    Then show that $$\dim (D-P)=\dim (D)-1$$ for almost all $P$.

I proved the first part of the question, but I couldn't prove $\dim (D-P)=\dim (D)-1$ using this first part.

Thanks

Source: first chapter of [Algebraic function fields and codes](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540768777) from Henning Stichtenoth

Answer (score 1):

Let $C$ be a curve over $k$, and $P$ a $k$-point.

Recall that we can think of $\mathcal{L}(D)$ as

$$\mathcal{L}(D)(U)=\left\{f\in K(F):\text{div}(f)\mid_U+D\mid_U\geqslant 0\right\}$$

Then,

$$\mathcal{L}(D-P)(U)=\left\{f\in K(C):\text{div}(f)\mid_U+D\mid_U-P\mid_U\geqslant 0\right\}$$

So, I think you can see that $\mathcal{L}(D-P)$ is a subsheaf of $\mathcal{L}(D-P)$, whose global sections correspond to global sections of $\mathcal{L}(D)$ vanishing at $P$. So, in particular, for almost all $P$, $\Gamma(C,\mathcal{L}(D-P))\subsetneq\Gamma(C,\mathcal{L}(D))$.

But, note that if we think of $\mathcal{L}(-p)$ as being the ideal sheaf of the closed subscheme $p\subseteq F$, then we have the exact sequence

$$0\to\mathcal{L}(-p)\to \mathcal{O}_C\to \mathcal{O}_p\to 0$$

Tensoring this with $\mathcal{L}(D)$ gives

$$0\to\mathcal{L}(D-P)\to\mathcal{L}\to \mathcal{L}(D)\otimes\mathcal{O}_p\to 0$$

Passing to global sections we get

$$0\to\mathcal{L}(D-P)(C)\to\mathcal{L}(D)(C)\to k$$

Which tells you that $\dim\mathcal{L}(D-P)(C)$ is either $\dim\mathcal{L}(D)(C)$ or $\dim\mathcal{L}(D-P)(C)-1$.

So, for almost all $P$, so that $\mathcal{L}(D-P)(C)\subsetneq\mathcal{L}(D)(C)$ you have the desired dimension.

Answer (score 1):

A variant on Alex Youcis's answer, maybe more direct:

Suppose that $P$ is not one of the points of $D$, so that functions $f \in \mathcal L(D)$ can't have a pole at $P$.  Evaluation at $P$ gives a linear map
$L(D) \to k$, whose kernel is $L(D - P)$.  So either this map is the zero map,
and $L(D-P) = L(D)$, or this map is non-trivial functional, and then
$L(D-P)$ has dimension one less than $L(D)$.

The map is non-trivial precisely if there is at least one $f \in L(D)$ such that $f(P) \neq 0.$   Any non-zero $f \in L(D)$ has only finitely many zeroes, for almost all $P$, we can be sure that $f(P) \neq 0$ for at least one $f \in L(D)$ (assuming
that $L(D) \neq 0$.)

---

If $P$ is one of the points of $D$, then the argument is similar, except that instead of evaluating at $P$, you should take the coefficient of the degree $-n$ term of the Laurent expansion of $f$ at $P$, if $n$ is the multiplicity of $P$ in $D$.

[Added: as Jyrki notes in comments, we can ignore this case anyway, since it only involves finitely many points $P$.]

---

The argument with sheaves that Alex Youcis gives abstracts this 
 argument with evaluation, or taking leading order coefficients, and has the advantage that you don't need to separate these cases (and of course many other
advantages, since it plugs into the whole sheaf-theory machinery).

Comment: +1 to you all. I have a suspicion that this question may have emerged relatively early in the development of the theory. Say we before Riemann-Roch and sheaves. Therefore I want to add the remark that you can actually leave out the stuff about Laurent expansions. After all, not dealing with the points in the support of the divisor $D$ does not change the conclusion that the claim holds for almost all $P$. The support is finite :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Re "The support is finite" :  very good point!  Thanks.

Comment: What is the evaluation $f$ at $P$? $f$ in the Stichtenoth's book is just an element of the field $F$ and $P$ is the maximal ideal of the evaluation ring $O_P$ in $F$. Thanks

Comment: @user42912: $F$ is the field of rational functions on a curve, so $f$ is a rational function, and $P$ is a point of the curve, so $f(P)$ is just the value of the function on the curve.  In more commutative algebra terms, *evaluation at* $P$ is the reduction map $O_P \to O_P/P = k$; but you will probably have more intuition if you learn to think in the more function-theoretic/geometric way I just described.